# Firebase Phone Authentication SMS autofill stopped working after changing package Name and Key store

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have an android app with Firebase Phone number authentication. Its working fine but recently I had to change my package and key store after that I had added my SHA1 & SHA256 in firebase console and everything is working fine but SMS code is not getting autofilled in EditText means onverificationcompleted is not getting called.
However If I changed my Application ID and create new firebase android app in firebase with new ID and put all my code there then same code and setup is working fine.
Like `com.example.app` is not working but `com.example.newapp` with same code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer as i tried to find out the solution but did not get any.
Finally I noticed that it was due to Long App Name in Play store.
So any one facing the same issue should consider to reduce App Name to 11 Characters.